# How to keep fetched data from Firebase when app is killed?

Tags: android, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

My app is fetching data like this. I want to keep fetched data from firebase if app is killed and use when app created again so I want to fetch data only when database is changed but not onViewCreated. I think that I should use room database. Firstly fetch data to room database then show the data from room database. If user enter new data the value event listener will work and fetch data to room database again. Is this a good way ? if not is there a good way to do this ?

```
@Override
public void onViewCreated(@NonNull View view, @Nullable Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onViewCreated(view, savedInstanceState);
    this.v = view;
    FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().setPersistenceEnabled(true);

    final RecyclerView productListView = v.findViewById(R.id.productList);

    final ProgressBar mProgresBar = v.findViewById(R.id.inventoryProgressBar);

    getDatabase();

    fetchProductsToRecyclerList(getContext(),productListView,mProgresBar);}
```

For example I am using value event listener and I want that app will fetch data only with this event listeners.

```
public void fetchProductsToRecyclerList(final Context context, final RecyclerView rv,
                                               final ProgressBar pb) {
    DatabaseReference myRef = getFirebaseRef();
    String userID = getUserId();
    myRef.child(userID).child("Products").addValueEventListener(new ValueEventListener() {
        @Override
        public void onDataChange(@NonNull DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {
            products = new ArrayList<>();
            pb.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
            int counter = 0;
            //Get all of the children at this level
            Iterable<DataSnapshot> children = dataSnapshot.getChildren();
            for (DataSnapshot child : children) {
                Iterable<DataSnapshot> cocuklar = child.getChildren();
                for (DataSnapshot cocuk : cocuklar) {
                    counter += 1;
                    Product prd = cocuk.getValue(Product.class);
                    if (!prd.getProductID().equals("0x0x00x0xx"))
                        products.add(prd);

                }
            }
            mAdapter = new ProductAdapter(context, products);

            RecyclerView.LayoutManager layoutManager = new LinearLayoutManager(context);
            DividerItemDecoration dividerItemDecoration = new DividerItemDecoration(rv.getContext(),
                    ((LinearLayoutManager) layoutManager).getOrientation());
            rv.addItemDecoration(dividerItemDecoration);
            rv.setHasFixedSize(true);
            rv.setLayoutManager(layoutManager);
            rv.setItemAnimator(new DefaultItemAnimator());
            rv.setAdapter(mAdapter);
            if (counter == 0) {
                //    emptyList.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
            } else {
                //    emptyList.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);
            }
            pb.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);
        }

        @Override
        public void onCancelled(@NonNull DatabaseError databaseError) {

        }
    });
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Any data you query with the Realtime Database SDK is going to be cached in local storage by default.  The cache will be used for subsequent queries, as long as the data is up to date with the server.  You don't need to do anything to enable this.  You don't need an additional cache, unless you need to query the data in some way that's different than what the SDK offers.

[Read about disk persistence in the documentation.](https://firebase.google.com/docs/database/android/offline-capabilities#section-disk-persistence)

Comment: I was using different way before asking this question and I was getting set persistenceis enabled method from different class and I can see now it was a mistake. Thank you.

Comment: Hi Doug! I guess your were thinking about Cloud Firestore, where offline persistence is enabled by default. In Firebase realtime database it should be enabled using `setPersistenceEnabled(true);`.